# Is p2p possible to use without port forwarding or NAT or upnp

Tags: c#, network-programming, p2p, nat, portforwarding

How can I communicate two computer. The computers must communicate among themselves and end user is not set modem or router configurations(nat , upmp , port forwarding)

User open program and program can change network configurations. Is it possible?

Comment: If you don't use a central server it's just impossible if no ports are open.

Comment: If there's no NAT then there's no problem.